# Setup restarts the laptop and then restarts the installation all over and over again?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using a USB

Comment: can you elaborate? Like when does it reboot? and does it boot directly to the usb again? did you try booting from the hard drive, as you probably set it to boot from usb by default?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It sounds like you are booting back into the usb on restart. When setup is shutting down the computer, it should ask you to remove the installation media then press enter. It will pause to give you a little time to do this, but then will continue on. Either remove the usb when prompted or interrupt the reboot to change your boot order so you can boot from the HD.

Comment: @chaskes  I will try doing what you said but it does not ask to remove the booting device

Comment: @sbergeron No I have not tried hard disk booting. Yes directly reboots to USB. It reboots t after I choose Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7 and click continue

Comment: so the installation never finishes?

Answer (score 1):

When it starts to reboot remove the usb as it is still set to boot the usb by default, and is thus booting right back into the installer.